# python - extract numbers from a string coming from serial port

Tags: numbers, extract

i receive this type of messages  in my Raspberry Pi from Serial Port ( in this case usb1) , and i want to execute some instrutions in this case os.system(instrutions) when i receive some numeric values but from
some strings and not from other strings.
whe start with Light:  .....    i want to receive value

example message receive in my serial interface:
"Light: 16 lx , quality: low"   -> i just want number 16
http : 200 ok   -> i don need this number 200

I have already one python cript in place but give error many times:

error messages
Light: 13 lx , quality: toolow
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "receive_serial_data_from_usb1.py", line 11, in 
if number [0] > 400 :
IndexError: list index out of range

```
//python script:

#!/usr/bin/env python3
import serial
import os
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 115200, timeout=1)
ser.flush()
while True:
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
        number = [int (s) for s in line.split () if s.isdigit ()]
        
        if number [0] > 400 :
            print ('HIGH ATTENTION!!!')
            os.system('sudo python control.py -t DA:74:56:99:71:DE -c move_down')
        if number [0] < 10 :
            print ('LOW ATTENTION!!!')
            os.system('sudo python control.py -t DA:74:56:99:71:DE -c move_up')
        else :
             print(line)
```

Can you help me?